# Calling API without a page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles1.css" />
    <script src="api.js"></script>
</head>

<body background="texture.jpg" class="bg">
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Awesome Quotes</h1>
        <p>Your daily dose of wisdom.</p>
        <div class="dynamic">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button" type="submit">Get a New Quote</button>
        </div>
        <div class="quote"></div>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  $(".quote").append(a[0].content + "<p>— " + a[0].title + "</p>")
});
```

these are my HTML and JS.what I'm trying to do is generate a random quote inside a div.I called an API for that.Every time I reload the page a random quote comes up.What I need to do is click the "Get a New Quote" button and get a quote without reloading the page using jquery.Plus I need to click the twitter icon to take me to twitter where i see the relevant quote already in the editor just to post.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

Give your button a class so you can easily access it

```
<button class="btn btn-primary getnewquote" id="button" type="submit">Get a New Quote</button>
```

Script

```
var Res;
    $('.getnewquote').click(function(){
    //your ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Your web service url",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (json) {
            Res = JSON.parse(json.d);
            $(".quote").append(Res[0].content + "<p>— " + Res[0].title + "</p>")


        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Wonderfull answer!! very good very very good i have been looking for this answer my whole life

Comment: what should be included in "your ajax call"?

Comment: Your webservice url
http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=